# How to use C++ Expects operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, cpp-core-guidelines

I'm starting a project using C++, which I haven't used before outside of a handful of school projects - nowhere near the scope of what I'm tackling now.

My goal is to try my best to follow the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) as I work to avoid errors, improve performance, and most importantly: improve maintainability of my code.

I've been running into *literally hundreds* of issues ranging from my g++ / Clang++ versions not being right to standard libraries not being found to g++ using the wrong version of C++ for compilation to very basic functions not behaving as expected - *and I haven't even started to look into autotools*, so I expect many more headaches to follow.

This question is specific to one part of the C++ Core Guidelines, though. [Interfaces 6: Prefer Expects() for expressing preconditions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-expects)

I tried writing the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int square(int x) {
    Expects(x > 0);
    return x * x;
}

int main() {
    cout << square(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This threw an error in g++:

```
$> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int square(int)’:
main.cpp:7:2: error: ‘Expects’ was not declared in this scope
  Expects(x > 0);
  ^~~~~~~
-> [1]
```

I tried using Clang, as well, but it has an entirely different (and unrelated) problem:

```
$> clang++ -x c++ main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
-> [1]
```

I haven't figured out how to fix that one yet, so I'm not bothering with it.

Comment: @Galk No such file or directory. Do I need to `sudo apt-get install` something to get the GSL stuff?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but a more modern build generator might be a good idea. I prefer Meson but CMake is a defacto standard. Either would help with your iostream issue as they will find all the normal stuff.

Comment: I'm actually reading up on CMake right now. I definitely need a better build system. I'm pretty new to C++ development so I'm re-learning everything I spent years figuring out with JavaScript and Python (what build tools exist, what dependency managers exist, how people structure projects, etc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Expects` is part of the GSL library. You have to use some GSL library implementation, which you can find on Github:

- https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite
- https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL

These are the ones I have off the top of my head.

The CPP Guidelines likely allude to [the "contracts" proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0287r0.pdf) which provides the same checks via attributes. It was scheduled for C++20, but later removed for lack of consensus on its scope. See [p1823r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1823r0.pdf) and a standard committee member's [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cmk7ek/what_happened_to_c20_contracts/) on the rationale leading to the removal.

Comment: It's very odd to read "guidelines" about how to use C++ well and find nonstandard recommendations.

Comment: Note that the link is now [https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/assert](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/assert).  gsl/gsl_assert is deprecated.

Comment: @RobertBernstein thanks. I've removed the suggestion as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from GSL, `Excepts` exists also in `C++20` not in `C++17` with a little different syntax

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract

Comment: How is `C++20` a thing? I thought the last two digits referred to the year the version was released (e.g. `C++14` came out in 2014, `C++17` came out in 2017, etc) -- wouldn't this mean that `C++20` came out in 2020? It's only 2019. Am I misunderstanding the naming convention? Also, how would I install and use `C++20`? When I try `g++ -std=c++20` it gives the error `did you mean -std=c++03?`

Comment: C++20 is still in phase of standardization. They probably meant C++2a, which is a placeholder for the incoming C++20.

Comment: Unfortunately `g++ -std=c++2a` gives me the same error :( I guess I'll just stick to `C++17` with the GSL for now

Comment: @MárioFeroldi: Nobody calls it "C++2a" except for compiler switches, and only then to express that it isn't a complete C++20 implementation yet.

Comment: The proposal has been dropped off C++ 2020, see https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cmk7ek/what_happened_to_c20_contracts/

Comment: @stevendesu starting in 2011 a new revision of c++ will come out every 3 years. In the process to the next revision there is a lot of discussion and experimenting before the revision gets finalized by all participants https://isocpp.org agreeing on how to implement specific features. "Contracts" is such a moving part which is experimented on for over a decade now.