# Why doesn't the [[expects]] attribute work?

Tags: c++

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void something(int i) [[expects: i != 1]]
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}

int main() {
    something(3);
    something(2);
    something(1); // exception should happen here
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error when compiling (even when I'm using the same syntax style I found in most places that covers this obscure attribute):
`error: expected ']' before ':' token`

Comment: What compiler version are you using? Are you sure it supports these attributes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `expects` being used this way and can't find much about it online. Can you share a link with more details?

Comment: @templatetypedef see https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/cppreference2018/en/cpp/language/attributes/contract.html

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is that a cached version of a cppreference page from 2018 describing a C++20 feature that did not actually end up in C++20? I think more detail about how the asker is compiling their code and what basis they have for thinking that the `expects` attribute would be present is necessary.

Comment: @NathanPierson "*Is that a cached version of a cppreference page*" - I don't know. It is just the first thing I found when I searched for `c++ expects attribute`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I think that’s a cached page from cppreference? I can’t find anything else about it online. The other Google hits didn’t look promising.

Comment: @templatetypedef
 [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/attributes-in-c/), [cppreference](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/cppreference2018/en/cpp/language/attributes/contract.html)

Comment: @KenY-N I'm using C++20 on g++

Comment: @BadUsernameIdea The cppreference link you’ve shared is an archived version from 2018, the same year the GeeksForGeeks article was written. I’m wondering if this was a proposed feature of C++20 that never came to be? That would explain why the compiler rejects it and why nothing turns up on Google.

Comment: [What happened to C++20 Contracts?](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cmk7ek/what_happened_to_c20_contracts/) -- First added to the language, and then removed again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, cppreference [deleted that page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract) and the attribute was dropped from C++20, as discussed in posts linked in comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521313/10871073).